# Add data in column in import data wizard

Tags: sql-server, import

Goal:
After using import data wizard and in the same table you want to add a new column that shall be contain numbers

Problem:
Is it possible to add a new column and inside of it you add value 1 that should take place in import data wizard?

If this csv has 5 rows and you add a new column. The new column shall contain value 1 only in relation to import data wizard.

Info:
*I don't have SSIS in my computer

It should be more auto and low manual work.

Thank you!

Comment: you can do it using BulkInsert of csv through query as well

Comment: I suggest [`BULK INSERT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365(v=sql.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new column on the table in SSMS through the interface or using the following script:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD column_name column-definition;
```

This would be Null by default unless you populated it.

You could then add this column to your input csv and upload via data import export wizard. This would

Comment: Thank you for your help! The request is that it should take place in import wizard that is by adding a new column and inside of this column you should add a new value that is number.

Comment: As far as i'm aware import wizard cant create columns. You could run an ssis package but you might as well just do this in SSMS